# Merge [multi-user] into [multiple-users]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-request

Merge the tag [mutli-user](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mutli-user) into [multiple-users](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-users). They refer to the same concept and the term *multiple users* is a little more clear than *multi user*.

And to convince you, I have dragged up the relic that is Trogdor the Burninator!

[image: Trogdor the Burninator!]

Comment: It looks like `status-completed`